# Java Entities Dates fields and Oracle TIMESTAMP data types

Tags: java, oracle, date, jpa, timestamp

In my entities classes I use to define the temporal fields as follows:

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    private Date start;
```

In my oracle DB the columns mapped by those fields are of type `TIMESTAMP`.

What are the implications of this configurations:
Are my dates implicitily UTC dates ?
Does it mean I have to be careful on handling by myself Daylight saving time issues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPA [`TemporalType.TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html#TIMESTAMP) corresponds to the JDBC [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) type, which in turn corresponds to Oracle's (and the SQL standard) `TIMESTAMP [ WITHOUT TIME ZONE ]` type. While JDBC 4.2 (Java 8) added support also for [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), Java EE 7's `TemporalType` is not there yet.

This means that your values do not have any time zone attached to them, the semantics of the timestamp is that of the "local time zone", whatever that is configured to be. Of course, you have to watch out for potentially different server (database) and client (machine running your Java application) "local time zones"!

You can achieve the desired behaviour if you *are sure* that client **and** server time zones are set to UTC.

Comment: thanks! please can you elaborate a little bit more on what you said about "the semantics is that of the "local time zone""

Comment: When you say client and server you mean Application server and RDBMS?

Comment: @GionJh: Edited to make this more clear. I *strongly* suggest you read up the documentation about this.

Comment: Yeah thanks I'm a little bit confused also because I thought java.util.Date only refers to UTC timezone and not your system time zone, is it right ?

Comment: It *is* confusing. Try to forget about `java.util.Date`. The fact that `java.sql.Timestamp` (and other types)  extend it was a very big early design mistake in the JDK libraries... The `java.sql.*` types are all *local time zone* types. Only with Java 8 and the `java.time.*` / JSR-310 types, we now have the possibility to somewhat predictably bind timestamps at a specific time zone (it was possible before using tricks and/or `java.util.Calendar`, but such a mess)

Comment: Ok so all is fine while server and rdbms are use the same local time, what about dayligt saving time issues ? (thanks for your time and effort by the way ;))

Comment: I'll let you figure that one out yourself :)

Comment: It is rising an error, if I'm testing right, is it the expected behaviour ?

Comment: Hey, @GionJh: Stack Overflow won't run out of question IDs too quickly. Feel free to ask a new, fresh question. Cheers

Comment: posted it ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803879/java-sql-datetime-daylight-time-saving-ambiguity